# get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class CofficientsDialog :
    global a,b,c
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.x=DoubleVar
        self.y=DoubleVar
        self.z=DoubleVar

        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Cofficient')
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.x).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.y).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.entry3 = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.z).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)

        self.label1=Label(self.master, text="X^2").grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=W)
        self.label2=Label(self.master, text="X").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.label3=Label(self.master, text="+").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W+E+S+N)
        self.label4=Label(self.master, text="+").grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W+E+S+N)
        self.btn_submit = Button(self.master, text="SUBMIT",
                                 command= lambda :self.submit()).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)

    def submit(self):
        a=self.x.get()
        b=self.y.get()
        c=self.z.get()
        self.master.destroy()
```

I want to get the value of EntryBOX but I am keep getting a error of

File "C:/Users/***/Desktop/Python Practise/Quadratic_Equation_Plot", line 27, in submit
    a=self.x.get()
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: If you want help, you need to elaborate on what exactly your problem is.

Comment: This is missing some tags for sure as I have no idea which library he is using and people seem to know

Comment: It's the python tkinter standard library.

Answer (score 2):

DoubleVar is a class, to use it, you must instantiate it, with

```
self.x = DoubleVar()
self.y = DoubleVar()
self.z = DoubleVar()
```

then the self parameter is automatically filled.

Comment: I have already initiated it in the Constructor.  Do I have to initiate again in the Submit method??

Comment: You did not instantiated them in the constructor, because the `()` after the class name `DoubleVar` wasn't there. You can replace your instantiation code and try it

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is running perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

you need to put
    master = self.master 
in the function