# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' (StringVar)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an application on tkinter and when I use `do_it` by pressing the `work` button I get an error.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Wiki Scrape')
root.geometry('640x640+0+0')



heading = Label(root, text = "WELCOME", font =('arial', 30, 'bold')).pack()
label1 = Label(root, text = 'Please type a link from Wikipedia: ', font=
('arial', 10, 'bold'), fg='black').place(x=10, y=200)
name = StringVar
entrybox = Entry(root, textvariable=name, width = 25, 
bg='lightgrey').place(x=250, y=202)


def do_it():
    print(name.get())

work = Button(root, text='Done', width=15, height=1, 
command=do_it).place(x=400, y=198)
root.mainloop()
```

and here's the error I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\et400\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/et400/Downloads/Coding/Python/WebScraping/WikiScrape.py", 
line 18, in do_it
    print(name.get())
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: @joe: if that were true, the error would be different.

Comment: This is almost identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362069/get-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self).

Answer (score 4):

You initialized all tkinter's objects, except StringVar, you should do this:

```
name = StringVar()
```

instead of `name = StringVar`

Now your variable name - instance of class StringVar and instances automatically pass argument 'self'.